# How to build ipa file with flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I've upgraded my flutter to version 1.26.0-1.0.pre

Now I'm trying to build ipa file with command

```
flutter build ipa --export-options-plist=ExportOptions.plist
```

File ExportOptions.plist contains such content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <true/>
    <key>destination</key>
    <string>export</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>ad-hoc</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>automatic</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>/*This is my team ID*/</string>
    <key>thinning</key>
    <string>&lt;none&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Output for build command is:

```
Running pod install...                                           1,691ms
Running Xcode build...
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        17.3s
Xcode archive done.                                         33.7s
Built /Users/alexeyzhulin/Projects/flutter/shopping-list/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive.
Building IPA...                                                  1,977ms
Encountered error while building IPA:
error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'ru.alexeyzhulin.shoppingList' were found
```

What kind of profile I have to add to my plist file?

I'm using automatic signing as you could see in my plist content and if I run

```
flutter xcodebuild -h
```

I could see

```
provisioningProfiles : Dictionary

        For manual signing only. Specify the provisioning profile to use for each executable in your app. Keys in this dictionary are the bundle identifiers of executables; values are the provisioning profile name or UUID to use.
```

How to build ipa file use command line flutter tool?

Answer (score 6):

My recommendation is to manually generate the IPA with XCode, at least the first time.
This will generate a .plist file named `ExportOptions.plist` in the same directory where your .ipa file is created.

Then, you can use the `ExportOptions.plist` file for your next deliveries by running this command :

```
flutter build ipa --export-options-plist=absolute/path/to/ExportOptions.plist
```

Everything is explained here :
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive-with-xcode

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following github action and it works well.

```
  - name: 'Upload app to TestFlight'
    uses: apple-actions/upload-testflight-build@v1
    with: 
      app-path: 'path/to/application.ipa' 
      issuer-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_ISSUER_ID }}
      api-key-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_API_KEY_ID }}
      api-private-key: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_API_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

Here is a detailed article to build and publish Flutter iOS app with github actions. Add above github action in the pipeline in the following article.

[Build and Publish Flutter iOS Apps](https://damienaicheh.github.io/flutter/github/actions/2021/04/22/build-sign-flutter-ios-github-actions-en.html)

Answer (score -2):

Below steps will work to generate `.ipa`

1. Run `flutter build ios` (it will generate `AppName.app` file)
2. Find above generated file in project structure `build/ios/iphoneos/AppName.app`(go to this location through finder)

3. Copy `AppName.app` and create a `ProjectName` folder on desktop or any location and paste `AppName.app` inside the newly created folder.
4. Compress the `ProjectName` folder(It will look like `ProjectName.zip`)
5. Finally, Rename `ProjectName.zip` to `ProjectName.ipa` and use this `.ipa`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try this solution

Comment: it doesn't work for me